# Can we Bring two Dataset at a time and compare it

Tags: java, multiple-resultsets

i have a **ResultSet** method **public ResultSet getItemPurchase(String Pid)** which return a Data from a  database table. similarly i have another method public **Resultset getItemSale(String sid).** i have called them using a function **ResultSet rs1 = getItemPurchase(Pid);** and next function is **ResultSet rs2 = getItemSale(Pid);**

i want to do as following.

```
 1. while(rs1.next)
 2. {
 3. rs1.getString("Item");
 4.      if(rs1.getString("price")==rs2.getString("price")
 5.        {
 6.          //some code here
 7.        }
 8.      else{
 9. rs1.getDate("Purchase Date");}
 10. rs2.getString("CustomerName");
 11. }
```

can anybody please help me on this

Comment: What issues are you having?  Error messages?  Unexpected results?

Comment: If both result sets come from the same database, then I'd improve the SQL query with something like `WHERE a.price = b.price` ...

Comment: in any case instead of "==" you should use "equals()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to write two domain objects, Plain Java objects like:

```
public class ItemPurchase{
    private String price;

    //setter/getter for price

    private String purchaseDate;
    //setter/getter for purchaseDate
}
public class ItemSale{
  private String price;

    //setter/getter for price

    private String customerName;
    //setter/getter for customerName
}
```

Now create a list of objects while iterating each resultset like:

```
public List createListOfItemPurchased(ResultSet rs){
 List<ItemPurchase> purchaseList=new ArrayList<ItemPurchase>();
 while(rs.next()){
   ItemPurchase purchaseObject=new ItemPurchase();
   purchaseObject.setPrice(rs.getString("price"));
 //fill all required data in it
  purchaseList.add(purchaseObject);
 }
  return purchaseList;
}
```

Same way populate the salesObjects and then create a method to filter out your results like:

```
filter(List purchaseList, List salesList){
  for(ItemPurchase purchaseObj:purchaseList){
    //process the objects according to your requirement
  }
}
```